# Is there any necessary to use tag plugins like simple tagging in wordpress 3.0+

Tags: plugins, tags

As there is tagging feature built-in wordpress already, but why so many people recommend "simple tagging" plugin. Now i just need a feature of tags link. Is there the built-in a easy way to implement it by built-in tag system? I often feel confused there are two places to input tags before my eye when editing post. And i'm afraid my tags will lost if one day i do not use this plugin anymore for some reasons

Comment: I assume you actually mean [Simple Tags](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-tags/) and not [Simple Tagging](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-tagging-plugin/) , right? The former looks like it compliments the existing tagging functionality, i can see how that would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Edit (now the answer on this question): The (former known as) "simple tagging" plugin seems to just add management features for tagging (like mass editing, etc.) plus allows tags for "pages" *). The all over look let's me think, that the plugin doesn't offer anything that's not delivered by wp core.

*) Pages & Posts are only builtin definitions of "post types", like categories & tags are builtin "taxonomies". So you got a 99% chance that none of your data get's lost even if you deactivate the plugin, as the data should stay in the postsmeta table.

Anyway, i'd suggest to look at the plugin code and/or ask the author about the possibility of data loss after deactivation or uninstall.

Comment: Did you mean to post this answer to a different question? If not, could you please clarify how an answer about adding filters to custom post types has anything to do with using a tagging plugin?

Comment: @Manzabar: Oh, ehm.. yes. Guess i answered some more questions at the same time. Sry.